# Can't see the votes on the question where people voted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, voting, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I can't see the reputation votes on the question where people voted me up. I can see it only in my profile. Is this intended?

Here is one example:
[Symfony Question: How to get/read the HTML content of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585582/symfony-question-how-to-get-read-the-html-content-of-a-page/8908728#8908728)

In my profile says I got 10 reputation upvotes from my post there, but when I enter that question, I only see 1 upvote instead the actual 10 upvotes.

Comment: "This question covers exactly the same content as ..."

In the FAQ you must click in expand reputation in order to see how it works. I think its not very intuitive for new users which quickly searchs for the vote and reputation system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each answer upvote gives you ten rep points, question upvotes give you five. Each downvote takes away 2. Each acceptance gives you 15.

It's all covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

> Aside: and questions about Stack Overlow itself (rather than programming) are meant to be asked on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Thanks, really simple and usefull. Thank you for the tip, I will do so in future questions :)